# How to assign n ports to a server in a multi client-server socket program?

Tags: python-3.x, networking, network-programming, serversocket

I need to define n ports for each server so that i can know if any server is connected to more than 1 client than at which port the connection is taking place.

```
import queue
import socket       
import random
import threading        
import pandas as pd

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"        
num_server = 3        
num_client = 7
server_thread_list = []      
client_thread_list = []       
sid = []        
sip = []        
dip = []        
connect = []      
l_info= []       
s_port = []        
topology_buffer = queue.Queue()        

def create_csv():
        source_mac = sid
        source_ip = sip
        dest_mac = connect
        destination_ip = dip
        link_info = l_info
        source_portno = s_port
        df = pd.DataFrame()
        df["Source_MAC"] = source_mac
        df["Source_IP"] = source_ip
        df["Source_Port_No"] = source_portno
        df["Dest_MAC"] = dest_mac
        df["Dest_IP"] = destination_ip
        df["Link_Info"] = link_info
        print(df)
        df.to_csv("network.csv", index = False)

def server(id):    
        UDP_PORT  = 5000 + id
        soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        soc.bind((UDP_IP,UDP_PORT))       
        while True:
            data, addr = soc.recvfrom(1024)
            data = data.decode()
            data1 = "S" + str(id)
            print("Server" + str(id) + "recieved message from" + str(data))
            topology_buffer.put_nowait(str(data1 + "<-->" + data))
            for i in range(len(data1)-1):
                sid.append(data1)
                ser_ip = '192.168.1.' + str(random.randint(0, 255))
                sip.append(ser_ip)  # generate ip address
                s_port.append(UDP_PORT)
                conn = data
                connect.append(conn)
                dest_ip = '192.168.1.' + str(random.randint(0, 255))
                dip.append(dest_ip)


def client(id):
        if id<= len(server_thread_list):
            UDP_Port = 5000 + id
        else:
            UDP_Port = 5000 + random.randint(0, len(server_thread_list))
        soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        message = ("C" + str(id))
        soc.sendto(message.encode(),(UDP_IP, UDP_Port))
        soc.close()
        create_csv()

def topology():
        while True:  
            link = topology_buffer.get()   
            print(link)
        for i in range (num_server):    
            t = threading.Thread(target = server, args=(i,))    
            server_thread_list.append(t)    
            t.start()    
        for i in range (num_client):
            t = threading.Thread(target = client, args=(i,))
            client_thread_list.append(t)
            t.start()

topology()
```

I want the result as, the port number to be printed along with the connection.

eg: Server S1a received message from c1 at port number 5002.
Server S1b received message from c2 at port number 5003.
Server S2b received message from c3 at port number 5004.

Comment: A server will normally listen on a single port so that the clients know to which port they should connect. The server then distinguishes clients by source addresses (network and transport).

Comment: A given socket can be bound to only one port at a time. So, the only way to open multiple server ports is to create multiple servers, one per port.

Comment: can you tell me how can i define the multiple server ports ?